# make systemd-run run in foreground while created cgroup has live processes

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to use `systemd-run --user --scope` as sort of the reverse of daemonizing a process, but without using root permissions.

I'm trying to use `systemd-run` to make a group of processes "behave like a single process".

I'd like the `systemd-run ...` process itself to stay in the foreground while any processes in the unit are still alive.

I'd also like it to be the case that when the `systemd-run ...` process exits,  the unit is cleaned up and all the processes in the cgroup "lose their right to exist" and exit as well.

when you run a process that doesn't daemonize (like emacs, by default), systemd-run appears to create a cgroup that lasts for the life of the process.

```
$ systemd-run --user --scope emacs
```

however when used with something else like `firefox`, which does run in the background, the process exits immediately (although it does put firefox in a new cgroup as advertised).

Is there some way to get `systemd-run` or some other `systemd` utility to present you an API like the one described above.

Comment: Are you sure firefox runs in background? I haven't tested the exact situation with it running under `systemd-run --user --scope`, but just running it on command-line looks like it's a foreground process to me... If you do have a background process to run in this case, maybe try using [fghack](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/fghack.html) to try to turn it into a foreground one?